# How to use Mantra with Meteor and Redux?

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs, redux, flow-router

I'm trying to get into mantra and wanted to use it with react, redux and flow router.
But I can't get redux right this time.

Github: https://github.com/saschb2b/kickstart-mantrajs-meteor-react

I injected context and actions in flow router with

modules/core/routes.jsx

```
export default function (injectDeps, { FlowRouter }) {
  const MainLayoutCtx = injectDeps(MainLayout);

 FlowRouter.route('/news', {
    action() {
      mount(MainLayoutCtx, {
        toolbar: <DefaultToolbar title="News" />,
        content: <NewsOverview />,
      });
    },
  });
```

but when dispatching an action the complete context is used instead of the desired value.
modules/core/componentsDefaultToolbar.jsx:42

```
this.props.store.dispatch(this.props.toggleMenu(this.props.menuOpen));
```

Should call `{type: "MENU_TOGGLE", open: false}`

Instead it calls
`{type: "MENU_TOGGLE", open: Object}` where Object is the complete context with     Meteor,Tracker, FlowRouter and Store

You can redproduce this by cloning my project, navigate to /news, resize your window to <1024 (which shows the burger button) and click the burger button. The console should now spit a bunch out.

Do I use redux wrong? Is my store not correctly initialised? If you got alternatives or tipps, I'll take everything

**Edit: Got to change my method on how the action creators are used. Seems good so far. But my components don't rerender if something changes in my state. Any idea? Latest change is in the repo**